# embedded font-family not rendering properly on ios 14

Tags: css, cross-browser, ios14

I converted a font I have permission to use in WOFF. in every other version of ios (13 and below) the font displays on the website properly. However, in IOS 14 (regardless of iPhone version) it shows up to the right and doesn't sit within the box-sizing I have. When I change the font family to whatever the browsers default it shows properly.

I am embedding as follows:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lunchtype-medium';
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/example/fonts/Lunchtype22-Medium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/wp-content/themes/example/fonts/Lunchtype22-Medium-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'), url('/wp-content/themes/example/fonts/Lunchtype22-Medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/wp-content/themes/example/fonts/Lunchtype22-Medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/wp-content/themes/example/fonts/Lunchtype22-Medium-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

as said originally, I dont have this issue on any other browser or os.

Answer (score 0):

apparently only otf and ttf font formats are supported in ios 14 right now. Please place on top of order list when using font-face.

^_^